# Transitive relations and Subsets

Tags: relations

I have a question to prove:
If relations R is transitive, than R^2 is transitive. In the answer the professor says that if R is transitive than:

R^2 is a subset of R (I understand why, this is the definision)
Therefore, R^2*R^2 is a subset of R^2. This is the part I don't understand. Is this like a multipication of two sides in an equation?

Thank you.

Comment: A relation $R$ on a set $A$ is a subset of the cartesian product, that is, $R\subset A\times A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You believe that $R^2=R\times R\subseteq R$.  Therefore, $$R^2\times R^2=(R\times R)\times (R\times R)\subseteq R\times R=R^2$$

Comment: thank you, but I still don't understand why. Is this because every parethesses are a subset of R?

Comment: That's right, if $A\subseteq B$ and $C\subseteq D$, then $A\times C\subseteq B\times D$.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you mean 
$$
R^2=\{(x,z):\text{there exists $y$ such that $(x,y)\in R$ and $(y,z)\in R$}\}
$$
In particular, since $R$ is transitive, from $(x,z)\in R^2$ it follows $(x,z)\in R$. Therefore $R^2\subseteq R$.

Now, suppose
$$
(a,b)\in R^2,\quad (b,c)\in R^2.
$$
Then, *by definition*, $(a,c)\in R^2$, since you know that $(a,b)\in R$ and $(b,c)\in R$.